# Which databases/sites do most people use for searching vulnerabilities?

Tags: search-engines

This is slightly different to this one [which site do you use to view details of vulnerabilities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/which-site-do-you-use-to-view-details-of-vulnerabilities)

My question relates to the differences between various websites for searching vulnerabilities.   I am aware of the following sites:

- National Vulnerability Database (NVD) (https://nvd.nist.gov)
- CVE Details (https://www.cvedetails.com)
- CVE Mitre (https://cve.mitre.org/)
- CIRCL CVE Search (https://cve.circl.lu)

The same CVEs can be found in all of these places.  My questions are:

1. What distinguishes each of these different websites?  Is it simply the same information available in multiple places with different maintainers?
2. Is there one recognized source of truth that the majority of security researchers go to?  Or is this country dependent?

Comment: What is listed as CVE should be the same on all sites. So what DB you use may end up being just a personal preference.

Comment: MITRE has a good references section that usually has a website with the specific details, if available, but not always. Sometimes a google search for that CVE or a specific description of the vulnerability will pull up somebody's research that is not listed on the CVE sites.