# Where can I find a description list for major vulnerabilities?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

I'm looking for a description list for major vulnerabilities such as SQLi, XSS etc.

The format should be like this:

> Short Description:
>   Description:
>   Impact:
>   Solution/How to prevent:
>   References:

Comment: Hi user3220381 - please read [ask] to understand what we need from questions here, and why your questions are all being closed.

Comment: possible dupe of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/which-site-do-you-use-to-view-details-of-vulnerabilities and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/829/how-to-keep-an-eye-on-upgrades-patches-and-security-issues-for-used-open-source

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention SQLi and XSS, this seems to be primarily about web vulnerabilities. In that case, take a look at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

If you're asking this from a developer's point of view, you will be especially interested in their Cheat Sheets. For example, here is the [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

The most famous place where to list and discuss vulnerabilities is probably [the Bugtraq mailing list](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive).

Answer (score 0):

A professionnal grade list of common vulnerabilities and exposures is available on the MITRE web server [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures](http://cve.mitre.org/cve/index.html).

For example if your would be interested in XSS: [search on CVE for ID on XSS](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=XSS&search_type=all&cves=on).

Answer (score 0):

I like http://www.cvedetails.com/ since it allows me to generate a feed and search by product and  version, but it is not the only place where I go to stay up to date, securityfocus.com (as mentioned in another answer) is also a very good resource. When it comes to staying up to date, my advise is not to rely on just one source, even reddit.com/r/security comes up with interesting things now and then.

Most often, the specific vendor also has a way of communicating changes in their versions, for example for MySQL Oracle [releases these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alerts-086861.html) every so often.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too detailed for you, but I recommend the [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures](https://cve.mitre.org/) list.
Although it's primary purpose is to provide a *dictionary* of common names (CVE Identifiers) for publicly known information security vulnerabilities, the fact that they are recognized and used throughout the industry makes them a source.
They partner with the U.S. National Vulnerability Database (NVD).

They have [RSS feeds](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/data_updates.html), or you can download their master lists or updates.

[They just changed their syntax](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/identifiers/syntaxchange.html) last januari 2015.

Others have built APIs around CVE [Google *cve api Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cve+api+Common+Vulnerabilities+and+Exposures) to find e.g. the [CVE-search](http://www.circl.lu/services/cve-search/) API developed by CIRCL.